# Got invalid pointer when using boost::object_pool with vector

Tags: c++

I tried to use `boost::object_pool` to create an object which contains a vector as its member data. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>

class A {
public:
    std::vector<int> children;
};

int main() {
    boost::object_pool<A> p;
    A* a = p.malloc();
    std::cout << a->children.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the result.

```
free(): invalid pointer
18446720595997429822
```

I was expecting the program to output `0`. However, as you can see, there was clearly something wrong here. The allocated pointer was not a valid pointer, why? What should I do to make it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating object using `boost::object_pool<X>::malloc` which only does memory allocation and does not call object constructor. Already you are calling `size()` for uninitialized object. Later upon exit the destruction of `p` results in uninitialized instance of `std::vector<int>` being destroyed (according to [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces) all allocated objects will be destroyed implicitly).

You should use `boost::objetc_pool<X>::construct` if you need object to be constructed. Just replace

```
A* a = p.malloc();
```

with

```
A* a = p.construct();
```

Comment: Thanks! No wonder it didn't initialize the object, turned out I used the wrong member function.